# Bypassing iframe sandbox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Someone iframing my website, using

```
<iframe src="http://example.org" sandbox=""></iframe>
```

This way, the sandbox attribute prevents my site to use iframe blocker on it. And it can be easily iframed.

Frame buster on my website:

```
if (window.top !== window.self) window.top.location.replace(window.self.location.href);
```

Is there a programmatic way **to redirect** to my site when its being iframed when used with sandbox attribute ?

Comment: In addition to other options, you might consider the [`X-Frame-Options` HTTP response header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options).

Comment: A more on info regarding iframe and framekillers [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Framekiller), [iFrame Attribute - html5 & Security](https://www.tinfoilsecurity.com/blog/protect-your-website-from-embedded-content-iframe-security)

Answer (score 18):

Iframing can be protected through the `X-Frame-Options` response header, set either `X-Frame-Options` `value="DENY"` or `X-Frame-Options` `value="SAMEORIGIN"`. Through this response header settings you can protect your website against IFraming or clickjack attack.

Once `X-Frame-Options` response header is set, browser receives a standard message like "This content cannot be displayed in a frame".

Comment: With that one, it wont show my page correct ? But as I bolded the text, I want it to redirect to my page.

Comment: Browser doesn't receive any proper html or script once X-Frame-Options response header is set either to "deny" or "sameorigin", so redirect is not possible through script.

Answer (score 11):

The sandbox attribute is turning off all javascript, amongst other things.  This is why your frame buster will not be working, nor any other javascript people have provided.

[W3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/iframe.html) say of a sandbox:

- scripts are disallowed/disabled within the iframe
- links to other browsing contexts are disallowed/disabled within the iframe

A test shows that the attribute also disables meta redirects and any standard link which breaks out of the iframe.

With this strictness, I'd be very surprised if a redirect is possible, since that would defeat the point of the sandbox.

The best I can suggest would be to use the noscript tag to display a message to users seeing the page in a sandboxed iframe. You could style that so people can't see your content.

(If it is just one site being a problem, then blocking them with htaccess would probably be a better approach)

Comment: Another person used with sandbox="allow-scripts" , so say that we can run javascript. What could be the best approach to redirect to main iframed site ?

Comment: They'd need allow-top-navigation for that to work.  Allow-scripts also does not allow leaving the iframe.

Comment: If that was also added, what could be the approach for redirection ?

Comment: I guess you need fallbacks for each potential outcome.  1. Redirect - for normal iframes  2. Show a message with javascript to say it can't be viewed in an iframe and to visit your site directly - for those with allow-scripts, and 3. The noscript version for the full sandbox.   2 and 3 aren't great for the user experience, but I really can't think of any better approach if you are to not block the iframe completely.

Comment: I really don't think you can redirect 2 or 3 (well, 2 seems to work if you right click and the user specifies to open in new window).  All you can do is give them a link to copy and paste.

Comment: I'd assume any site owner who sees you redirecting would just remove the iframe anyway, so I don't see why a redirect is all that better from a block.

Comment: It might also be worth just asking the site owner to use a link instead of an iframe embed - some people are nice!

Answer (score 2):

I think the best thing you can do is show your own message with a `target="top"` link. The whole concept of the sandbox attribute is to disallow redirects. There is no way to bypass that and if you ever find one browser makers will probably find a way to stop it. It's clearly their intention.

This is just how the web works. You can't do whatever you want when it comes to browsers.

Answer (score 1):

@SudiptaKumarMaiti's answer of `X-Frame-Options` works, but is being superseded by Content Security Policy (CSP) Level 2 - specifically the `frame-ancestors` [directive](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors).

To disallow framing completely (similar to `X-Frame-Options: DENY`), use this HTTP header:

```
Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors 'none';
```